# Moving up a directory with HTML from JS dom

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first time posting so any points would be nice about formatting or what not, but here's my problem anyway.

This is my JS Code

```
document.getElementById('mainnav-up').innerHTML =
"<div class='banner'>" +
"<a href='..\index.html'><div class='button'></div></a>" +
"</div>";
```

Which places a button on my HTML page under :

```
home/products/product1.html
<div id="mainnav-up"></div>
```

but instead of being taken to

```
home/index.html
```

I am instead taken to

```
home/products/..index.html
```

Which is non-existent.
If I then hard code the link into the `home/products/product1.html` page it takes me to the index page correctly, but I'd like to be able to just edit one piece of code for the whole website.

Comment: How would `home/products/product1.html` ever be the same as `../index.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<a href='..\index.html'>
```

to

```
<a href='../product1.html'>
```

Comment: Ok i am so confused now.
I changed it to <a href='../index.html'>
Which worked correctly, i thought it was always '..\' to go up a directory? as i have used else where  in the site